# I want payment in paypal with dynamic price entered by user

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, paypal, payment, rate

I want payment in paypal with dynamic price entered into textbox in wordpress. can anyone help me?according to user choices and price rate list,total price will change and will be calaulated by user.user will enter that amount in textbox which will be paid in paypal.How to do this? I did research on it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use code similar to the following, where you have a text box for the buyer to enter in the amount.  Then they click the button to make a payment and they will be redirected over to PayPal with that amount.

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="my_site@my_site.com">
<!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Hot Sauce-12 oz. Bottle">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="text" name="amount" maxlength="60">
<br />
<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks.I ll try this one and I'll let u know.If anyone wants to use another currency code then what I should do?

Comment: You could create a drop down menu for allowing the buyer to select the currency code.  You would just need to populate the drop down menu with the currency codes that PayPal supports.  Also keep in mind if you change the currency code, this may also effect what you would need charge for the amount if you are selling items.  So you would need to populate the amount accordingly.